# Minimizing coefficients in a product related to the Rogers Ramanujan identity

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, power-series, partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

Start with the product for partitions into parts congruent to $1$ or $4$ modulo $5$:
$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...)(1 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{12} +...)(1 + x^6 + x^{12} + x^{18} +...)$...

Now replace some of the plus signs with minus signs and expand the product into a series. Is it possible that the coefficients of the resulting series can all be in the set {$+1,0,-1$}?

This is a variant of the question ["A Product Related to Unrestricted Partitions"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146359/a-product-related-to-unrestricted-partitions) asked by David Newman about six years ago.

Comment: Are you hoping that, with sparser factors (i.e., skipping $(1+x^2+x^4+ \cdots)$ and $(1+x^3+x^6+ \cdots)$ and their analogues modulo 5), this is more tractable than David's question?

Comment: Indeed, my father was hoping that this case would be more tractable. I suppose there is some chance that one could show this case to be impossible by a brute-force backtracking computation. Initial computations suggest this is unlikely though.